# Cordova app with C#/XAML for Universal Windows app

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-universal

I just created a Cordova app for WP8(it uses C# and webView). Its working fine as expected. But when I try to create equivalent in Windows8.1, it always creates Html/JS as programing language. I would like to create it in C# with WebView similar to WP8(I know it uses Silverlight framework).

The application I am trying to create is not a pure Hybrid application. The web pages I actually host in a web server instead within the app. In this case android, iOS and WP8 are working fine. I heard about hosted web application using ManifildJS but I cannot change the application as a lot of invest has been already done for the current approach....

In html/js version an equivalent Webview i can see(like iframe) but that does not fit for our requirement. I deliberately need C# version of the app in Cordava because of some complex operations. Could anyone find out any solution on this? please help......

Comment: Did any one got any answer? please help....